# Include a JSP file in another JSP file and modify the parent HEAD or BODY?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp

Using:
Apache Tomcat 6
Spring 4.0

Let's say I have a "child" JSP file that contains a link to an external javascript file:

I then include the child.jsp in the middle of my parent JSP-file the resulting HTML would be something similar to below:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<lotsOfHTML>
<!-- start injected JSP -->
<injectedHTML>
  <script src="my-external-file.js"></script>
<!-- end injected JSP -->
<evenMoreHTML>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<lotsOfHTML>
<!-- start injected JSP -->
<injectedHTML>
<!-- end injected JSP -->
<evenMoreHTML>
  <script src="my-external-file.js"></script>  <-- Injected Javascript
</body>
</html>
```

Clarifying:

This is what my JSPs looks like:

`index.jsp
   include1.jsp
   indclude2.jsp`

index.jsp has the meat of the page, like the header and such.
include1.jsp and include2.jsp contains stuff like widgets and other components that I wish to reuse on my pages. This includes CSS and JavaScript libraries.

By default any included references to external CSS and JavaScript would be included in the middle of the page.
I want the JavaScript libraries to appear at the bottom of the page that the includeX.jsp is included on.

How can I achieve this?
Worst case(?) would be to include the JavaScript file in the HEAD, but preferably at the bottom of the BODY-tag.

Thanks!

/J

Comment: IMHO not possible, but I am not an expert. Would like to see an answer from someone with a deeper insight.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished using JSP tag files.  For example:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my-tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Stuff goes here -->
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- Content goes here -->
       <my-tags:javascript />
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript.tag**

```
<%@tag description="JavaScript libraries for all pages." pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
```

When `index.jsp` gets processed into HTML by Tomcat, the contents of your tag files will be injected into the JSP.  You could also wrap the tag reference in a conditional EL evaluation, if you don't always want the JS injected into the page.

Comment: Is the javascript.tag tidbit in another template or is that part of another file in WEB-INF?

Comment: @Roralee: If you notice the top of the `index.jsp` snippet, `.tag` files are all kept in a separate directory: `/WEB-INF/tags`.  You don't need any more than what you see in this answer to make this work.

Comment: Thank you for providing the extra tidbit re: WEB-INF/tags subdirectory. I don't work play in that area of the pond on a regular basis and that was the key I needed to figure out how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a way around for your requirement. Go for two jsp page, `header.jsp`, which imports all `.css` files. `footer.jsp` for importing `.js` files. Now configure your `web.xml` to make use of these jsp page throughout the webapp.

```
<jsp-config>
   <jsp-property-group>
     <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
     <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
     <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
     <is-xml>false</is-xml>
     <include-prelude>/template/header.jsp</include-prelude> <!-- header -->
     <include-coda>/template/footer.jsp</include-coda> <!-- footer -->
   </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>
```